# webkitNotifications - SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 - script, OK - button

Tags: html, google-chrome, notifications

I followed http://www.beakkon.com/tutorial/html5/desktop-notification tutorial for html 5 desktop notifications. The demo on that page work for me. If i copy entire code it works so, but... when i call the method from javascript it don't display niether the notification or permision request. Instead it raises `SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18`.

It seems the error is raised by the line which creates the notification itself.

Has anybody glue why button works and calling the function directly does not?

---

My current code:

```
function RequestPermission(callback)
{
  window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission(callback);
}

function notif() {
  if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() > 0) {
    RequestPermission(notif);
  }

  notification = window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification('http://localhost:3000/images/rails.png');
  notification.show();
}
```

Does not compute:

```
notif();
```

Computes:

```
<button onclick="notif()">NOTIFY</button>
```

Google Chrome:  9.0.597.84 (Oficiální sestavení 72991)

WebKit: 534.13

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18` is valid if the user hasn't allowed your request to have notifications.

The reason why this is happening is simply because `requestPermission` is asynchronous. Once the user clicks on <kbd>Allow</kbd>, for permission to be granted, it will then allow you to use HTML5 notifications feature.

In your case, your not waiting for the user to click on <kbd>Allow</kbd> button, it is automatically trying to create the HTML5 notification without evening waiting for their confirmation. If you rearrange your conditionals, it should work.

```
function RequestPermission(callback) {
  window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission(callback);
}

function notif() {
  if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() > 0) {
    RequestPermission(notif);
  } else {
    notification = window.webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification('http://localhost:3000/images/rails.png');
    notification.show();
  }
}
```

As you notice above, place the notification creation in the conditional statement, when a callback gets fired it will be guaranteed to have permission.

Comment: Thank you it works. But still is mistery for me why the in-script invocation of notif() does not fire up the requestPermision. Now when i load the page it does not do anything(including throwing errors), i click the button, grant the permission, reload page and notification is here.

Thank you again

Comment: Your code should work (after you fix the conditionals). Once the user allows the notification permission, it will automatically show the popup (no need to refresh).

Comment: Yes, but still - invoking notif() from javascript does not do anything before a click button with onclick="notif()" and then Allow

Comment: I find it very odd that checkPersmission == 0 when it is enabled, and 1 when not. Very counter-intuitive.

Comment: checkPermission returns a possibility of 3 states; not true or false.  0: allowed, 1: not allowed, 2: denied.  I guess they chose to escalate .  Makes more sense!?

Comment: The following code runs in my case: **window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission(callback);** But it does absolutely nothing. I mean I don't get any message where I can allow the notifications. My chrome version is: **21.0.1180.89 m**. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the createHtmlNotification accepts only one parameter, and that is to be 
a url to an HTML document.

Comment: My problem is that it works in one case and does not in another. What you describe would lead to not working in both cases

Comment: There are simple notifications(with 3 parameter) and http notifications that show a webpage.  Documentation and sample code available at html5rocks.com.    http://playground.html5rocks.com/#simple_notifications