# How to fix SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18?

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile

I'm developing jQuery mobile application for iPad.

- jQuery version: jquery-1.6.4.js
- jQuery mobile version : jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.js

I'm getting this error when I load in iPad.

> SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through
>   the security policy of the user agent.

```
<%   
    if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("iPad"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("LoginiPad.aspx");       
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("LoginSP.aspx");  
    } 
%>
```

Can any one tell me how to fix this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704929/uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913866/webkitnotifications-security-err-dom-exception-18-script-ok-button and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511378/security-err-dom-exception-18-on-using-getimagedata-in-a-chrome-extension

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the new version of iOS tries to disable redirecting based on the user agent string. I can understand, some of the web apps websites try to direct at us iPad users are paired down to the point that they suck. I don't know what voodoo Apple's using to try detecting when this happens, but I bet if you took the "iPad" out the name of the file it might help.